# My message input doesn't get into database

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to send a message to a friend but it doesn't want to get into my database but it shows in the url afterwards even if i use $_POST. I get my currentuserID and my recipientID (the person I need to send to) cause I var_dump those both and get both ID's. My SQL query shouldn't be wrong I thought that I have checked with multiple people (but when I tested in the database it gave an error. BUT when I put another query in it that works, it gave the same error so I don't think that's a problem).

So I have no idea what can be the problem here..

My message.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//Hier mag enkel het gesprek te zien zijn tussen 2 users die met elkaar bevriend zijn
//tabel buddies >buddyID1 & buddyID2

include_once(__DIR__."/inc/header.inc.php");
include_once(__DIR__."/classes/Message.php");
include_once(__DIR__."/classes/User.php");

$userArray = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$userID = implode(" ", $userArray);
$currentUser = $userID;

//var_dump($_POST);

$recipientID = implode(" ",$_POST);//om het getal terug te krijgen van de recipientID
echo "currentUser: ";
var_dump($currentUser);
echo ".  recipientID: ";
var_dump($recipientID);



//msg wordt in databank gestopt
if(!empty($_POST['message'])){
    $msg = new Message();
    $msg->setUserID($currentUser);
    $msg->setRecipientID($recipientID);
    $msg->setMessage(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
    $msg->messageSchrijven();
}

//msg wordt afgedrukt/gereturned
$msg2 = new Message();
$messages = $msg2->messagePrint();


?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" methd="post">
        <h1>Je chat nu met <?php echo $recipientID ?></h1>
            <input type="text" name="message">
            <input type="hidden" name="recipientID" id="" value="<?php echo $recipientID?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="senderID" id="" value="<?php echo $currentUser?>">
            <div class="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="width: 90px">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>
        <div>                
        <p><?php echo $message["senderID"].": " . $message["content"]; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>


</body>
</html>
```

my class Message.php:

```
<?php 
include_once (__DIR__ . "/Db.php");
class Message{
    private $userID;
    private $message;
    private $recipientID;

//getter setter userID
    public function getUserID()
    {
        return $this->userID;
    }

    public function setUserID($userID)
    {
        $this->userID = $userID;

        return $this;
    }

// getter setter recipientID
    public function getRecipientID()
    {
        return $this->recipientID;
    }

    public function setRecipientID($recipientID)
    {
        $this->recipientID = $recipientID;

        return $this;
    }

//getter setter message
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;

        return $this;
    }

// om je berichtje in de DB te steken
    public function messageSchrijven(){ 
            $conn = Db::getConnection();

            $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO msg(senderID,recipientID,content) values(:senderID,:recipientID,:content)");
            $statement->bindValue(":senderID", $this->getUserID()); // huidige user
            $statement->bindValue(":recipientID", $this->getRecipientID()); // de user naarwaar het verstuurd wordt
            $statement->bindValue(":content", $this->getMessage()); // het bericht
            $result = $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
    }

// berichtje afprinten
    public function messagePrint(){ //$senderID,$recipientID
        $conn = Db::getConnection();
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from msg where senderID = :senderID AND recipientID = :recipientID"); //where senderID = :senderID AND recipientID = :recipientID
        $statement->bindValue(":senderID", $this->getUserID());
        $statement->bindValue(":recipientID", $this->getRecipientID());
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }


}
```

I get my recipientID from another page where my "buddyies" have been listed, if I push on 1 of them I get his/her userid with me to the "message.php" page.

So I don't know if it is something with my query or I lose my userID's when I try to send it. But I've tried testing it with setting manually the userid's with

```
$msg->setUserID("9");
$msg->setRecipientID("10");
```

but it doesn't work.. (currentUserID = 9, recipientID = 10 at the moment btw).
Same problem with the printing of the messages.. I don't get them.
Database is connected cause I can log in and register with no problem.

Comment: Do you get any values from your formular? Because you wrote the method wrong - correct it to  `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: An insert does not fetch after execute.

Comment: @UfguFugullu it showed into my url but omg, didn't even see that i wrote that wrong.. 
it doesn't get into the database yet. But now it shows what I post in the 
<h1>Je chat nu met <?php echo $recipientID ?></h1>
now. So is it possible that the $_POST for the recipientID 
$recipientID = implode(" ",$_POST);
blocks the way to get my message post in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPLODE**

First of all I think you misunderstand the implode method. In your example the `$recipientID`

```
$recipientID = implode(" ",$_POST); //om het getal terug te krijgen van de recipientID
```

must contain something like "10 9 This is my Message" and that's no id. Add some verifications and change it to

```
$recipientID = $_POST['recipientID'];
```

You find some informations about [implode on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

**PDO EXECUTE**

If you are using PDO, the execute method returns a boolean (search on [php.net PDP execute](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php)). So if you don't use the return value, just use it like this

```
$statement->execute();
```

Additionally remove the `$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` line at the insert method.

**ERRORS**

After the `execute()` of PDO you can use

```
print_r($statement->errorInfo());
```

to get errors of your query. You can get more Informations [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.errorinfo.php)

**DATABASE**

We can't see your database schema, could it be that you offend against unique keys of your table or the type of field?

**HTML**

From my point I would always write space between variable name and php declaration like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="recipientID" value="<?php echo $recipientID; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you, $recipientID = $_POST['recipientID']; fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help you. @Tishier of this is the answer please mark it